# SSRS Count Distinct Type in a Column with non-numeric values

Tags: reporting-services, count, ssrs-2008

I have a report that shows new ‘Contacts’ that have subscribed to a level of service that is offered. I am trying to add a Column (Tier/Level of Service) within SSRS that has the possibly of many different values.

What I am trying to do is get a count of each new person added to a Tier of service. What I have right now does this, though it is sloppy and I was wondering if there is another way to accomplish this.

```
=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!TierLevel.Value = "Gold", Fields!ContactId.Value, Nothing))
=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!TierLevel.Value = "Silver", Fields!ContactId.Value, Nothing))
```

This gets a little messy as there are around 15 different levels that I have to total. The messy part of this is making it so the values are on top of each other when there is no data. I can hide a row but it leaves me with a blank spot. Frustrating and does not look very pretty.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Can you create a function in the Report Properties - Code to take the TierLevel and return a count? It'll be reusable and cut down on the clutter in that particular row or cell.

Comment: Why don't you handle it in TSQL? If you have all your tier levels ranked in a table, you could simply count the DISTINCT ContactIDs that came into the existence during your defined period of time (for example, during the previous month).

Comment: @mceda I can't do it through TSQL because the information in the table is different on the report. I am filtering out the information based on a series filtrations. I need only the totals of the information being displayed and not those of the entire table.

Comment: @BClaydon I will give that a try and post the results back when I have completed it. Thanks for the suggestion.